# .net standard project references incompatible nuget package version at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, xunit, .net-standard

I'm having a runtime issue with one of my NuGet dependencies in a .NET Core 2.0 project.

I'm taking a dependency on NuGet package B, which depends on NuGet package A. NuGet package B is a multi-targeted package with the following dependency graph:

```
Package B
  -- netstandard1.3
     -- package A 1.0
  -- netstandard 2.0
     -- package A 2.0
  -- net452
     -- package A 1.0
  -- net461
     -- package A 2.0
```

Here's my issue: I consume NuGet package B as a .NET Standard 2.0 package and everything compiles just fine and all my XUnit specs pass when I run via the Visual Studio 2017 test runner.

However, when I run XUnit on the CLI or on our build server, we get a bunch of `MissingMethodException`s which all point to `Package A 1.0` being referenced at runtime instead of `Package B 2.0`.

Any ideas on what the issue might be? Tried all of the usual steps with locking down the `Package B` version to `[2.0]` but that has not helped.

Comment: Tried clean&rebuild? Not that some false packages exist in output directory and do not get replaced.

Comment: At least you should dig into MSBuild/dotnet logs on the CI agent machine to see how the build was exactly executed. Merely post the above information is useless.

Comment: @dsdel yep, had no impact.

Comment: @LexLi not a helpful comment dude. Why bother posting useless slop like "check the logs?"

Besides, the build server logs and dotnet restore logs weren't helpful. They show the correct NuGet package version being restored but don't offer any indication as to what target framework version is being used.

I added some debug logging to my spec and it showed that the down-version of Package A, 1.0, was being used iinstead of 2.0. Exactly like I described in my post.

Comment: Though you might luckily find out the solution, your style of posting is like a one man show. Nobody but yourself can see the projects, so if you do not post enough information for others to reproduce it (log files, and so on), the question itself is of low quality http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: I gave you as much information as I had, which wasn't much. No downgrade warnings, nothing obvious from the restore logs, and the fact that this behavior was different inside VS and on the .NET CLI. I laid out the structure of the dependency and I described how the expected behavior was different from the underlying behavior. Aside from creating a Github repo with a nearly identical solution to the one I'm working on, I put as much information in as I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was with XUnit 2.3.0 - when the specs were running the `dotnet xunit` command executed the process as some target other than .NET Core 2.0, hence why the lower framework versions of the package were used.

Upgrading to XUnit 2.3.1 fixed the issue - the test now executes correctly as a .NET Core 2.0 spec and loads the correct version of the underlying dependency.